# How to develop this feature with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

What I want to achieve is as follows:

For example, there is a symbol which represents a table on a web page, a user can drag this element to any place on the web page, when the user looses the cursor, a dialogue box will pop up to ask the user to input values of attributes, for example,the number of columns, the number of rows, after the input, the corresponding table will come out at the place where the user chose. Of course, the symbol which represents a table is still at the original place. It is like a web version of dreamweaver. How to do this with Javascript?

Comment: If you are not clear, just ask for clarification.

Comment: You're basically asking someone to write your whole application for you. Try Googling "javascript drag and drop", "jquery ui dialog", "jquery ui drag and drop", etc., then ask questions when you run into trouble.

Comment: It is not simply drag and drop. It is more complex than that.

Comment: Then you should try something simpler. None of us have the time to be your teacher, that is not what this site is for. We are also not here to write the entire application for you, and you wouldn't really learn anything from that either. I'm sorry if this seems harsh, but you should really look into this yourself, or start with something simpler. I know that sounds boring and it is a lot more fun to just jump straight into the really complex stuff, but you need to learn how to walk before you start running. Once you have looked into how to do this you can come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: It is to drag a copy of the original element here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to start researching this feature I'd start with:

- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to get started with fancy yet easy javascript functionality
- [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/): [Draggable](http://ui2.jquery.com/demos/draggable/), [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), etc

To actually develop the feature, if you don't know where to start, start small.  Create a very basic web page with maybe just an icon and a button and then write some javascript to do something minor like display a dialog and show the result.  Slowly start adding things like dragging something around, etc.

The JQuery UI stuff has lots of demos that you can start out with as a base to start customizing.

**Warning:** The first time I hit the JQuery UI Demos page I wasted at least a couple of days playing with all their cool stuff.  It's so easy because the source is right there and you can also see it working in the browser on the demo page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the jQuery UI demonstration pages?  The [simple photo manager](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) demo contains all the major pieces you'll need: Dragging an item, handling the drop event, doing something custom on drop.  The [revert demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert) may also be of interest

Answer (score 0):

Begin by defining the requirements of your project. Break it down into smaller tasks and milestones. Then some learning and research on what javascript and frameworks like jquery can provide. Also check for existing solutions or components that you may be able to use and reduce your development efforts.